# What is the best practice when creating a class in java made out of other classes

Tags: java, class, oop

I am working on an Object oriented programming assignment in school and i was wonder what is the best way to create an object made up of other objects. in my assignment i have to create a car object with four other obects (engine,body,gasTank,transmission) i have already made these classes but i have no clue how to make a constructor in my car class that uses these objects as a parameter. just looking for guidance any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Pass them in as parameters? Use the builder pattern? Use plain setters? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Sounds like the canonical [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Attach the code for you car class, and then we could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you created all the classes in the same package:

```
class Car {
    private Engine myEngine;

    public Car(Engine engine) {
        myEngine = engine;
    }

}
```

And now you can call the Car object like this:

```
Car myCar = new Car(new Engine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this. I am assuming your e.g. `Car`
class has the fields: `engine`, `body`, `gasTank`, `transmission`.

```
public Car(Engine engine, Body body, GasTank gasTank, Transmission transmission){
   this.engine = engine;
   this.body = body;
   this.gasTank = gasTank;
   this.transmission = transmission;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the car could look like this:

```
public Car(Engine engine, Body body, Gastank gastank, Transmission transmission) {
    this.engine = engine;
    this.body = body;
    this.gastank = gastank;
    this.transmission = transmission;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might think of the real world to help you find your answer.  A Car has an engine, body, gasTank and transmission.

So you might consider :

```
public class Car {

    Engine engine;
    Body body;
    GasTank gasTank;
    Transmission transmission;

    public Car() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(Body body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public GasTank getGasTank() {
        return gasTank;
    }

    public void setGasTank(GasTank gasTank) {
        this.gasTank = gasTank;
    }

    public Transmission getTransmission() {
        return transmission;
    }

    public void setTransmission(Transmission transmission) {
        this.transmission = transmission;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that like any other method, a constructor for a class can be given parameters. For example:

```
public class Car {
    private engine;

    public Car(Engine eng){
        engine = eng;
    }
}
```

The code for your `Body`, `GasTank` and `Transmission` classes would be similar. You could then create a new `Car` by passing in each of the individual components:

```
Car car = new Car(engine, body, tank, transmission)
```

(assuming that `engine`, etc. have already been appropriately defined).

You can also have a default constructor, where no parameters are passed in and the new `Car` instance uses default parts:

```
public Car(){
    engine = new Engine()
    body = new Body()
    tank = new GasTank()
    transmission = new Transmission()
}
```